# how to sort a list view by file size in php

Tags: php, mysql, file, sorting

I have a listview with 4 columns - Name,Size and Date.The Size field contains file size like 10.18 KB,368.47 KB,3MB etc.The size of the file taking from FTP.How can I sort these file size in ascending or descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a ghost column with files size in bytes. Then you'll be able to sort your listview easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
From (
  SELECT name, size, 
  case 
  when substring(size, length(size) - 1) = 'KB' then 1024 * size
  when substring(size, length(size) - 1) = 'MB' then 1024*1024 * size
  when substring(size, length(size) - 1) = 'GB' then 1024*1024*1024 * size
  end size_in_byte
From `file_tab`) a
order by size_in_byte
```